# Trackpad interaction without touching it since spilling water

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad

I am using MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9.2.

2 days back some water was spilled(more like sprinkled) on the keyboard area of macbook and I immediately cleaned it. After that my macbook cursor behaves strangely. It acts like some one else is playing with the trackpad.

Below are my observations

1. In TextEdit if I leave it untouched, it selects a line of text and gets deleted. And some times if the text edit is not maximized, the focus moved out and brings back the window which is maximized. And also the cursor suddenly jumps to somewhere else while I am writing.
2. In VLC it continuously toggles between full screen and windowed mode. It automatically right clicks and opens the context menu.

Please help find the root cause and a solution please.

Comment: Does this also occur when booting in safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

The basic working of a trackpad is when a charged object such as a the human finger interacts with it. In case of a water spill, I assume you have wiped and cleaned it but still some amount of moisture has managed to slip into the trackpad and when it gets charged it starts interacting with it. I would suggest to take it to a repair shop, or if you still want to test it you can connect the external trackpad and check as that should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like someone's controlling your computer to me.

Go to System Preferences, then go to the Sharing preferences and see if Remote Management is turned on. If it is, turn it off.

Comment: How come this person started playing with the mac only when there was a spill? and is that person always on the same network?